# Is there way get the GPU-load average per second?

Tags: hardware, gpu

I am interested to get the GPU-load average over, for example, an interval of one second.

Alas, I was unable to find a direct way to get this information with the current API or tools ( vcgdb or vcgencmd ).

Any suggestions or ideas to accomplish this are welcome. Or alternatively, of course, an explanation why at this moment it is not possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

At this point it simply isn't possible. The makers of the RPi's GPU aren't particularly forth coming with access to the chip. Since we aren't provided with an API to get the GPU's load, any attempt at determining the load would be little better than a feeble guess.